# C# not writing to Database

Tags: c#, sql, insert

I read the topics about inserting data into Databases but clearly I didn't get the concept. I'm trying to add the values of the variables into a local SQL Server Express, the columns have the same name as the variables.
I at least trying to follow the other posts or the Microsoft docs, but it's clear that I missed something. What would I need to add to make this work?

```
namespace WeatherAPIs
{
class API_Data_Mine
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        
        //Defines The client as WebClient and setup the HTTP Header
        using var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "C# Weather API");
        client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

        //Download the JSON result from the DarkSkyBaseURL on API_URL Class
        string darkskyresult = client.DownloadString(API_URL.DarkSkyBaseURL);
        var darkskyjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(darkskyresult);
        //Print int the screen the result of the raw and unbeauty JSON download, wait for the user to press a key to resume
        Console.WriteLine(darkskyresult);

        string openWResult = client.DownloadString(API_URL.OpenWeatherBaseURL);
        var openWJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(openWResult);
        //Print int the screen the result of the raw and unbeauty JSON download, wait for the user to press a key to resume
        Console.WriteLine(openWResult);

        string watherBitResult = client.DownloadString(API_URL.WeatherBitBaseURL);
        var weatherBitJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(watherBitResult);
        //Print int the screen the result of the raw and unbeauty JSON download, wait for the user to press a key to resume
        Console.WriteLine(watherBitResult);

        //Parse and beautify the JSON Output from DarkSky URL
        JObject JDarkSKy = JObject.Parse(darkskyresult);
        JObject JopenW = JObject.Parse(openWResult);
        JObject JWeatherBit = JObject.Parse(watherBitResult);

        ////Write the beautified JSON from DarkSKy on screen and wait for the user to press a key to exit
        Console.WriteLine(JDarkSKy);
        Console.WriteLine(JopenW);
        Console.WriteLine(JWeatherBit);

        ///Mine the JSON selected JSON data and print it on screen

        var DSTemperature = (string)JDarkSKy.SelectToken("currently.temperature");
        var DSPressure = (string)JDarkSKy.SelectToken("currently.pressure");
        var DSWindSpeed = (string)JDarkSKy.SelectToken("currently.windSpeed");
        var DSRealFeel = (string)JDarkSKy.SelectToken("currently.apparentTemperature");
        var DSUvIndex = (string)JDarkSKy.SelectToken("currently.uvIndex");
        var DSHumidity = (string)JDarkSKy.SelectToken("currently.humidity");

        var OWTemperature = (string)JopenW.SelectToken("list[0].main.temp");
        var OWPressure = (string)JopenW.SelectToken("list[0].main.pressure");
        var OWWindSpeed = (string)JopenW.SelectToken("list[0].wind.speed");
        var OWRealFeel = (string)JopenW.SelectToken("list[0].main.feels_like");
        var OWHumidity = (string)JopenW.SelectToken("list[0].main.humidity");

        var WBSolarRadiation = (string)JWeatherBit.SelectToken("data[0].solar_rad");
        var WBUltraViolet = (string)JWeatherBit.SelectToken("data[0].uv");
        var WBWindSpeed = (string)JWeatherBit.SelectToken("data[0].wind_spd");
        var WBTemperature = (string)JWeatherBit.SelectToken("data[0].temp");
        var WPressure = (string)JWeatherBit.SelectToken("data[0].pres");
        var WBRealFeel = (string)JWeatherBit.SelectToken("data[0].app_temp");
        var WBHumidity = (string)JWeatherBit.SelectToken("data[0].rh");


        //UV only works wqith paid keys
        //var OWUvIndex = (string)JDarkSKy.SelectToken("list.main.");

        Console.WriteLine("Temperature on Dark Sky is - " + DSTemperature);
        Console.WriteLine("Pressure on Dark Sky is - " + DSPressure);
        Console.WriteLine("Wind Spped on Dark Sky is - " + DSWindSpeed);
        Console.WriteLine("Real Feel on Dark Sky is - " + DSRealFeel);
        Console.WriteLine("Ultra Violet Index on Dark Sky is - " + DSUvIndex);
        Console.WriteLine("Humidity Index on Dark Sky is - " + DSHumidity);

        Console.WriteLine("Temperature on Open Weather is - " + OWTemperature);
        Console.WriteLine("Pressure on Open Weather is - " + OWPressure);
        Console.WriteLine("Wind Spped on Open Weather is - " + OWWindSpeed);
        Console.WriteLine("Real Feel on Open Weather is - " + OWRealFeel);
        Console.WriteLine("Humidity on Open Weather is - " + OWHumidity);            

        Console.WriteLine("Solar Radiation on WeatherBit is - " + WBSolarRadiation);
        Console.WriteLine("Ultra Violet level on WeatherBit is - " + WBUltraViolet);
        Console.WriteLine("Wind Speed on WeatherBit is - " + WBWindSpeed);
        Console.WriteLine("Temperature on WeatherBit is - " + WBTemperature);
        Console.WriteLine("Pressure on WeatherBit is - " + WPressure);
        Console.WriteLine("Real Feel on WeatherBit is - " + WBRealFeel);
        Console.WriteLine("Humidity on WeatherBit is - " + WBHumidity);

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=[ServerName];Database=WeatherValues;Trusted_Connection=true");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO WeatherAPIs (DSPressure, DSWindSpeed, DSRealFeel, DSUvIndex, DSHumidity, OWTemperature, OWPressure, " +
            "OWWindSpeed, OWRealFeel, OWHumidity, WBSolarRadiation, WBUltraViolet, WBWindSpeed, WBTemperature, WPressure, WBRealFeel, WBHumidity) VALUES (@DSPressure, " +
            "@DSWindSpeed, @DSRealFeel, @DSUvIndex, @DSHumidity, @OWTemperature, @OWPressure, @OWWindSpeed, @OWRealFeel, @OWHumidity, @WBSolarRadiation, @WBUltraViolet, " +
            "@WBWindSpeed, @WBTemperature, @WPressure, @WBRealFeel, @WBHumidity)");

        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@DSPressure", DSPressure);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@DSWindSpeed", DSWindSpeed);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@DSRealFeel", DSRealFeel);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@DSUvIndex", DSUvIndex);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@DSHumidity", DSHumidity);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@OWTemperature", OWTemperature);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@OWPressure", OWPressure);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@OWWindSpeed", OWWindSpeed);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@OWRealFeel", OWRealFeel);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@OWHumidity", OWHumidity);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@WBSolarRadiation", WBSolarRadiation);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@WBUltraViolet", WBUltraViolet);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@WBWindSpeed", WBWindSpeed);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@WBTemperature", WBTemperature);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@WPressure", WPressure);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@WBRealFeel", WBRealFeel);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add = ("@WBHumidity", WBHumidity);

    }
}
}
```

I know that there are other posts here about it, but I'm just not being able to make this work with the reading material. :(

**EDIT:**

I changed the following:

```
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("The System Date and Time is - " + now);

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=[Server_Name];Database=WeatherValues;Trusted_Connection=true");
        conn.Open();


        SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO WeatherAPIs (DSPressure, DSWindSpeed, DSRealFeel, DSUvIndex, DSHumidity, OWTemperature, OWPressure, " +
            "OWWindSpeed, OWRealFeel, OWHumidity, WBSolarRadiation, WBUltraViolet, WBWindSpeed, WBTemperature, WPressure, WBRealFeel, WBHumidity) VALUES (@DSPressure, " +
            "@DSWindSpeed, @DSRealFeel, @DSUvIndex, @DSHumidity, @OWTemperature, @OWPressure, @OWWindSpeed, @OWRealFeel, @OWHumidity, @WBSolarRadiation, @WBUltraViolet, " +
            "@WBWindSpeed, @WBTemperature, @WPressure, @WBRealFeel, @WBHumidity)");

        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DSPressure", (System.Data.SqlDbType)DSPressure);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DSWindSpeed", (System.Data.SqlDbType)DSWindSpeed);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DSRealFeel", (System.Data.SqlDbType)DSRealFeel);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DSUvIndex", (System.Data.SqlDbType)DSUvIndex);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DSHumidity", (System.Data.SqlDbType)DSHumidity);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OWTemperature", (System.Data.SqlDbType)OWTemperature);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OWPressure", (System.Data.SqlDbType)OWPressure);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OWWindSpeed", (System.Data.SqlDbType)OWWindSpeed);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OWRealFeel", (System.Data.SqlDbType)OWRealFeel);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OWHumidity", (System.Data.SqlDbType)OWHumidity);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@WBSolarRadiation", (System.Data.SqlDbType)WBSolarRadiation);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@WBUltraViolet", (System.Data.SqlDbType)WBUltraViolet);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@WBWindSpeed", (System.Data.SqlDbType)WBWindSpeed);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@WBTemperature", (System.Data.SqlDbType)WBTemperature);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@WPressure", (System.Data.SqlDbType)WPressure);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@WBRealFeel", (System.Data.SqlDbType)WBRealFeel);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@WBHumidity", (System.Data.SqlDbType)WBHumidity);
        //insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DTTM", (System.Data.SqlDbType)now);

        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to resume.");            

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Now it's giving me this error:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   CS1656  Cannot assign to 'Add' because it is a 'method group'
```

Comment: The method you've chosen for writing to a database is very old.  Wouldn't you prefer something like Entity Framework or Dapper?

Comment: In addition, since you're using Newtonsoft.JSON to deserialize, *you should already have a C# object containing the requisite properties.* There should be no need for all of those JObjects and SelectTokens.  I suggest you take your JSON and plug it in [here](https://json2csharp.com/); it will generate some C# classes for you that correspond to your JSON mapping.

Comment: Both `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` implement `IDisposable`.  You are going to want to use a `using` statement to assure that they get disposed.  If you are going to do things this way (rather than using *Dapper* or *Entity Framework*, you will need to actually execute that command (`ExecuteNonQuery` or `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`) once you have everything setup.  You may find doing this in a GUI framework (like Windows Forms or WPF) more approachable.

Comment: @Flydog57 I believe the only reason SqlCommand implements IDisposable is in case you don't dispose of the connection yourself but dispose of the command, which contains the connection and can take care of its child IDisposable objects.

Comment: By the way, if I didn't make it clear, the reason the INSERT isn't happening is that you don't `Execute` the associated command. @insane_developer: I've always used `using` on both commands and connections - other than `HttpClient`, I dispose everything I use that's disposable

Comment: I personally think it's a good idea for new devs to understand how ADO.Net works, and you only learn by doing. Some of us where coding when it was the only option. All of these frameworks boil down to ADO.Net anyway.

Comment: Just add `insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` at the end of your code

Answer (score 0):

Try change your code to following code.

```
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@YourParameter", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Some of your values (no need to be string).";
// OR
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YourParameter", "Some of your values (no need to be string).");
```

because you calling the .Add(string parameterName, SqlDbType sqlDbType) it is just preparing the paremeter and parameter type, but no actual value is given.